# Use Neo4j for Content-Based Filtering?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I have two entities:
- Beer
- Users

The Beer entity has i.e. following attributes (Sweetness 1-10, Bitterness 1-10, TasteAttributeX 1-10, TasteAttributeY 1-10, Country, Region etc.

The User will later apply different actions (Relationship) such as ratings (1-5).

The problem:
How can I get beers that are similar (Based on Sweetness, Bitterness, TasteAttributes) to the ones I've liked before.

How would you create the datamodel in Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective; there will be many different ways of doing this, but here's one suggestion.

First, bin your continuous variables into categorical variables.  What I mean by this is, say you have sweetness ranging 1-10, break it up into three categories (low [1-3], mid(4-6], high [>6]).  Do this for each.

Second, create an "index node" for each category.  Something like this:

```
CREATE (l:Sweetness {label:"Low"});
MATCH (b:Beer),(l:Sweetness {label:"Low") 
WHERE b.sweetness <= 3 
CREATE b-[:sweetness]->(l);
```

Do this for each of your "categories".

Then, you can find related beers by those that have similar profiles:

```
MATCH (b:Beer { type: "ThisOneIKnowIReallyLike" })-[:sweetness]->(sweetCategory:Sweetness)<-[:sweetness]-(otherBeer:Beer),
      b-[:bitterness]->(bitterCategory:Bitterness)<-[:bitterness]-(otherBeer)
WHERE b <> otherBeer
RETURN otherBeer;
```

Now you've got a list of beers that meet those same categories.